# What classes should I attend to start professional reportage photography?

Tags: learning, street-photography, photojournalism

I want to be a master of street and reportage photography in the near future. But most  classes are teaching fashion photography and similar.

Comment: i live in Europe

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a class you can take.

newspapers are the primary (and almost only) customers for this kind of photography - and currently the entire newspaper industry is dieing.

Newspapers are scaling down and firing good, experienced photographers - those are the people you are competing against when looking for a job.

So you either have to be considerable better than people with years of experience (and no class is going to get you there) or be considerable cheaper (not a good strategy unless you like to be poor)

Sorry, the market you are trying to enter no longer exists.

The good newspaper photographers have already moved to commercial and magazine work.

The above-average are competing for a shrinking number of jobs that are paying less and less

The average and below are either unemployed or will be unemployed in a few years.